# How to tell if adding an edge to a DAG forms a directed cycle?

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph, topological-sort

Assuming I have a DAG and a given topological order function for every vertex v in the graph, when looking at 2 particular nodes: x, y which I know that |top(x)-top(y)|<10 how can I tell if adding the edge x->y will form a cycle in the graph?
I'm trying to achieve a solution that is better then O(V+E)...

What I thought was just checking if top(x) > top (y), if it is then we created a cycle.
But i'm afraid I might miss a case, also, does the fact that |top(x)-top(y)|<10 give me any additional info? any enlightments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the fact that `|top(x) < top(y)| < 10` to find an efficient solution.

First, note that if `top(x) < top(y)` there is no cycle. Otherwise, let `ar[] = y, z₁, z₂ … z_k, x` be the nodes in the topological sort between y and x. If there is a path from y to x, it can only go through these vertices. So just check if there is a path:

```
haspath[] = {false}
haspath[1] = true
for i = 2 to k+2
  for j = 1 to i-1
    if haspath[j]==true and edge(ar[j],ar[i])
      haspath[i] = true
      break
```

There is a path from y to x iff `haspath[k+2]` is true.

Answer (score 0):

It does miss a case.

```
     >x
    /
  >v
 /
r
 \
  >y

0  1  2
```

where `top(r) = 0` and `top(v) = top(y) = 1` and `top(x) = 2`. It's fine to connect `x->y`, but the `top` function has to change.

What we do know is that, if there's a path already from `y` to `x`, then the intermediate nodes have `top` less than `x`'s, so we can ignore the other nodes while traversing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand your example, but I didn't understand what you meant by your next sentence, what should I do then, to determine if a cycle has been created?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer When you're trying to find if `x->y` makes a cycle, you're trying to find if there's an existing path from `y->x`. Currently you're proposing to do this by traversing from `y`. I'm telling you to skip nodes  whose `top` is greater than or equal to `x`, because those nodes definitely cannot reach `x`.

Comment: Based on that, in the worst case if y is the first in the order and x is the last, I have traversed on every node in the graph, reaching O(V+E)

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer Yes, it's not better in the worst case. You'll want to look into algorithms for online topological sorting if that's what you want.

Comment: it's just that it's a specific case of adding only one edge